# Check if stdin has a white spaces

Tags: c, whitespace, stdin

How to check if in stdin it has a white spaces ?
In this example I want to count all white spaces in av[1].
But I don't know how to represent white spaces begin with a '\' in av[1].

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int count;

    count = 0;
    if (ac == 2)
    {
        while (*av[1])
        {
            if (*av[1] == ' '|| *av[1] == '\t'||*av[1] == '\r'|| *av[1] == '\v'||*av[1] == '\n'||*av[1] == '\f')
            {
                count++;
            }
            av[1]++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    else
        printf("Error\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Intput

```
./a.out "\n"
```

Output

```
0
```

Comment: Do you want to check whitespaces in the arguments or stdin? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Also, show what you have tried and how you failed

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Arguments passed to the program is NOT the same as stdin. I cannot see anything in your program that deals with stdin.

Comment: Please construct a [mre] and include expected and actual behavior for a given input

Comment: Ok i try to clarify my ask ! Thanks for the recommendation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the shell does some magic before passing the arguments. If you send the arguments quoted it will work:

```
$ ./a.out "this string has four spaces"
4
```

At least it will work for spaces. How whitespaces are escaped is shell dependent.